# Inserting zero-valued rows

Tags: sql

I have the following structure. All I want to achieve is that if for some reason one of the categories does not exist then rather than there being no row for that category there should be a row with zeros for x/y/z.

The following seems a bit convoluted - what is the correct way to achieve this?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.xxx;
INSERT INTO dbo.xxx
    values
    ('cat_1',0.0,0.0,0.0),
    ('cat_2',0.0,0.0,0.0),
    ('cat_3',0.0,0.0,0.0),
    ('cat_4',0.0,0.0,0.0);


--:: category 1
INSERT INTO dbo.xxx
SELECT  Category = 'cat_1',
        x       = SUM(x),
        y       = SUM(y),
        z       = SUM(z)    
FROM    dbo.yyy x
WHERE   DateKey >= period1;

--:: category 2
INSERT INTO dbo.xxx
SELECT  Category = 'cat_2',
        x       = SUM(x),
        y       = SUM(y),
        z       = SUM(z)    
FROM    dbo.yyy x
WHERE   DateKey >= period2;

--:: category 3
INSERT INTO dbo.xxx
SELECT  Category = 'cat_3',
        x       = SUM(x),
        y       = SUM(y),
        z       = SUM(z)    
FROM    dbo.yyy x
WHERE   DateKey >= period3;

--:: category 4
INSERT INTO dbo.xxx
SELECT  Category = 'cat_4',
        x       = SUM(x),
        y       = SUM(y),
        z       = SUM(z)    
FROM        dbo.yyy x
WHERE   DateKey >= period4;

SELECT  Category,
        x       = SUM(x),
        y       = SUM(y),
        z       = SUM(z)
INTO    #temp
FROM    dbo.xxx
GROUP BY Category;

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.xxx;

INSERT INTO dbo.xxx
SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

Comment: Its not realy making sense exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @astander I think it was written so long ago that I missed the obvious use of the `COALESCE` function that Trinimon pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` or `NVL` to define an alternative to `NULL`

```
--:: category 1
INSERT INTO dbo.xxx
SELECT  Category = 'cat_1',
        x       = COALESCE (SUM(x),0),
        y       = COALESCE (SUM(y),0),
        z       = COALESCE (SUM(z),0)    
FROM    dbo.yyy x
WHERE   DateKey >= period1;
```

Comment: +1 no need for the group by - but the inclusion of `COALESCE` has sorted it - surprising the workarounds that you can find in legacy code!

Comment: To which database was your question related? Due to `TRUNCATE` I thought it was ORACLE, but it wasn't, was it? I'm just curious ... ;)

Comment: SQL-Server but I think the script is Standard?

Comment: Just looked through some documentation - seems in fact pretty standard, apart from SQLite and other rather compact databases. Good to know ...